# how to uninstall visual-studio-code insider

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, uninstallation, deb

I have installed visual studio code from .deb package that I downloaded from its official site. but I can't uninstall it now. I tried all methods in [how to uninstall visual studio code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771334/how-do-i-uninstall-visual-studio-code)  . but none of them worked. some were not able to find code. Any suggestions on how to uninstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally visual studio code and visual studio code-insiders is installed through snap install that resides into your `/snap/` folder. to check whether a package is installed or not through snap install.( when you install it by running `sudo snap install code` or `sudo snap install code-insiders` or install from ubuntu software.)

**1.**  GO TO `/SNAP` FOLDER AND look for folder with package name.( **in our case: look for code-insiders**)
or
open **terminal** and type

```
$ snap list
```

find out the exact name of the application there. 
now run

```
$ snap remove code-insiders
```

now it is uninstalled. you can verify by typing in terminal

```
$ dpkg -l
```

this command shows all kinds of packages installed through any means on the system. or type

```
which code-insiders
```

it should not print anything (just an \n character and the line changes.)

**2.** if any chance this method fails then go to ubuntu software. and search for code-insiders in search tab. from there you can uninstall it.
Note: this might not appear in the list of installed applications when you click **installed** tabs beside **all** tab